# General formula for $P(a_1 \le X_1 \le b_1,\dots, a_k \le X_k \le b_k)$ in terms of the joint CDF

Tags: probability-theory

I know that :

$$
P(a_1 \le X_1 \le b_1,a_2 \le X_2 \le b_2) = F_{X_1 X_2}(a_1,a_2) + F_{X_1 X_2}(b_1,b_2) - F_{X_1 X_2}(a_1,b_1) -F_{X_1 X_2}(a_2,b_2)
$$

Where $F_{X_1 X_2}$ is the joint cumulative distribution function. I'm not really sure how this result is derived though, and I want to know if there's a general method for $X_1,X_2,X_3$ or $k$ random variables.

Comment: Hint: draw a picture

Comment: This has been answered before. The idea is that $$\mathbf 1_{a_1 < X_1 \leqslant b_1,\ldots,a_k < X_k \leqslant b_k}=\prod_{n=1}^k(\mathbf 1_{X_n\leqslant b_n}-\mathbf 1_{X_n\leqslant a_n})=\sum_I(-1)^{|I|}\prod_{n=1}^k\mathbf 1_{X_n\leqslant c_n(I)},$$ where the sum runs over every subset $I$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, $c_n(I)=a_n$ for every $n$ in $I$ and $c_n(I)=b_n$ for every other $n$. Integrating both sides yields $$P(a_1 < X_1 \leqslant b_1,\ldots,a_k < X_k \leqslant b_k)=\sum_I(-1)^{|I|}F(c_1(I),\ldots,c_k(I)).$$ Note finally that ...

Comment: ... every $a_n \leqslant X_n \leqslant b_n$ in the question should actually read $a_n < X_n \leqslant b_n$, as in this comment, and that the sum on the RHS has $2^k$ terms, for every $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How they are derived is quite easy, once you realise what the symbols mean. The formula you state is I think incorrect; see below.

We want to know when $a_1 \le X_1 \le b_1$ and $a_2 \le X_2 \le b_2$ both hold.

So we want at least the probability when $X_1 \le b_1$ and $X_2 \le b_2$. This is given by $F_{X_1 X_2}(b_1,b_2)$, by its definition. But we want also $X_1 \ge a_1$ and $X_2 \ge a_2$, and either of these can fail, or both (!).

So we substract $F_{X_1 X_2}(b_1, a_2)$ and $F_{X_1 X_2}(a_1,b_2)$ because these cover the probabilities that $X_1 < a_1, X_2 \le b_2$, which is one way to fail to satisfy and $X_1 \le b_1, X_2 < a_2$, which is another way to fail (while still being below the upper bounds).

But then we overcompensated: we substracted the probability that both $X_1 < a_1$ and $X_2 < a_2$ twice (!), and this is given by $F_{x_1X_2}(a_1, a_2)$, so we add back once that probability. So we get:

$$P(a_1 \le X_1 \le b_1; a_2 \le X_2 \le b_2) = F_{X_1 X_2}(b_1, b_2) + F_{X_1, X_2}(a_1, a_2) - F_{X_1, X_2}(b_1, a_2) - F_{X_1 X_2}(a_1, b_2)$$

As an aside: it's quite clear if you draw a picture of $[a_1, b_1] \times [a_2, b_2]$ in the plane (say with all of it in the positive quadrant) and consider the probabilities as areas in the positive quadrant (filling the square from $(x,y)$ to the origin. This picture is sort of correct, if $F$ would be a uniform distribution, e.g.

For higher dimensions you'd have a similar inclusion-exclusion formula, which will I think get $2^n$ terms for $n$ variables. Try $n=3$ for starters.